# How to redo changes on top of an updated mainline (part of undoing a faulty git merge)

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

I am looking over this document on how to undo a faulty merge: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.html

and I am wondering how to redo a feature branch's pull request after it has been mistakenly merged. I don't want to change the history of the mainline branch. To redo the pull request, I think I need to redo changes on top of an updated mainline after a revert commit. Otherwise, my original commits won't show up in the new pull request's diff because they are already part of the mainline's history.

Within that document, here is the section that I am have trouble following:

> if the developers of the side branch discarded their faulty A and B, and redone the changes on top of the updated mainline after the revert, the history would have looked like this:

```
---o---o---o---M---x---x---W---x---x
              /                 \
      ---A---B                   A'--B'--C'
```

where my feature branch was merged with `B` at the head, `M` is the merge commit, and `W` is the revert of my feature branche's merge commit. So if I am working on that feature branch, how do I redo my changes to create a branch with `A'--B'--C'`? Should I cherry pick all of my existing commits?

Basically, I am looking to go from here:

```
---o---o---o---M---x---x---W---x---x
              /                 
      ---A---B
```

to here:

```
---o---o---o---M---x---x---W---x---x
              /                 \
      ---A---B                   A'--B'--C'
```

`git rebase <mainline-branch> <feature-branch>` does not create new commits from the existing commits, because those commits are already part of the history (despite the merge having been reverted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should checkout x and create a new branch, then cherry-pick the commits A and B. This will give you your final diagram.